# Swap opened dialog on top of newly opened modal window

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi, dialog

I have situation where I have one 'flying dialog' which is usually opened in winforms application. Now I need to open other dialog window which have to be modal. The problem is that after opening modal dialog I need to have access to that 'flying dialog' but I don't have because it is under.

I found that when I open new dialog from context of modal dialog for example like this

```
private void ModalDialog_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            f3 = new OtherDialogWichShouldBeOverModal();
            f3.Show();
        }

        private void ModalDialog_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            f3.Activate();
        }
```

My window is over dialog window. And everything under modal is disabled so I can navigate between modal dialog and other window opened from context of modal.

Unfortunately I don't want to implement it like this because my flying window have to maintain a state and generally I don't want to dispose that object and open once more from context of modal dialog.

Do you know a solution how to swap opened dialog over other newly opened modal dialog to have access to both ?

Comment: Pass the owner in the show call ?

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/205381). Please read [Window Features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx) to understand, what factors affect the Z-order. [Dialog Boxes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632588.aspx) explains, how modality is implemented, and how to implement a modeless dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [EnableWindow API function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646291(v=vs.85).aspx) like this

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool EnableWindow(IntPtr hWnd, bool bEnable);

private void ModalDialog_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Application.OpenForms.Count; i++)
    {
        var f = Application.OpenForms[i];
        if (f is OtherDialogWichShouldBeOverModal)
        {
            EnableWindow(f.Handle, true);
            f.Activate();
            //...
        }
    }
}
```